# Setting focus on first cell of grid column with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, event-listener, ag-grid

I'm working to implement keyboard navigation between header and body cells of a grid in AG-Grid. Each header has a `col-id`, while each cell in the column has the same id. I have a script that will listen for a keydown event, and if the `e.key` event is `ArrowDown` while on a header, it should look for the `col-id` of the header, and search for the first cell in the associated column with the same `col-id`, then set the focus to that cell with `focus()`.

I have the following, but it is only logging out the columns `col-id`, and not getting a reference to the data cell below on key down

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if(e.key === "ArrowRight") {
    let headerId = document.activeElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("col-id");
    console.log('header id: ', headerId);
  }
  else if(e.key === "ArrowDown"){
    //get column id on arrowdown
    let headerId = document.activeElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("col-id");
    console.log('header id: ', headerId);
    //look for first child in first row with same id as header and set focus
    document.querySelector('.ag-cell').focus();
  }
  else if(e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    //store value of grid cell column id
    let cellId = document.activeElement.getAttribute("col-id");
    console.log('header id arrow up: ', cellId);
    //set focus to column header
    document.querySelector('.ag-header-cell[col-id="' + cellId + '"]').focus();
  }
});
```

Current state: [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/cgkFVBEpJ9FxZ4jM1iIp?p=preview)

Comment: Still trying to do this? Oh man. If you ever get this working, it's going to be incredibly fragile. You possibly want `document.querySelector('.ag-cell[col-id="' + headerId + '"]').focus();`.

Comment: @thirtydot - That's what I was looking for, thanks! Supposed I need to do it in the other direction for ArrowUp to go from the body cell to the header cell of the same column.

Comment: @thirtydot - I got this stuff figured out. If you can post your comment as an answer, I'd like to mark it as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To focus the first cell in the associated column when pressing the down arrow:

```
document.querySelector('.ag-cell[col-id="' + headerId + '"]').focus();
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯